# webdav search returns 405

Tags: ios, webdav

I am building a client application for webdav. I have implemented webdav protocols like MKCOl, delete, prop find, move, copy and it is working fine. When I tried to implement search method, server returns:

> 405 method not allowed

I am using apache2 server, do I need any configuration change in the server? I got to know from the link [How to get the list of folders and files deployed on Linux WebDav?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099428/how-to-get-the-list-of-folders-and-files-deployed-on-linux-webdav) that some servers will not support search method, and suggestion given from the link is to use webdav `propfind` method, so I want to know whether propfind with depth infinity is feasible for file system with large collections.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can craft the `PROPFIND` request to [limit the fields](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc2518.html#rfc.section.8.1.1) that are returned.  If you were to limit this request to the searchable parameters, it could work for you.

> [is] depth infinity feasible for file system with large collections

It depends, of course, on how large the collections are.  You will be receiving several hundred bytes of data for each item in the collection.  A collection with millions of objects could result in a pretty big response!

Comment: Thank you john for the clarification

Comment: using propfind with depth infinity instead of search method is better option or is there any fix to work server side search method.

Comment: Support for `SEARCH` simply may not exist in Apache2. To the best of my knowledge `SEARCH` is not a widely-supported WebDAV feature -- it's the result of a later RFC and not part of the 'core' specifictation.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response,I will go with prop find with depth infinity option  for doing a search,but I want to make sure depth infinity works for apache2 server.Do I need any configuration change in the server side to make depth infinity to work , please suggest ...

Comment: You can verify that Apache2 support infinite-depth by making a tree several folders deep and seeing if the PROPFIND returns everything.

Comment: I have implemented search with depth infinity , configured allow depth infinity at server side and  did a local search with the response,thanks for your support

Comment: any truncation(like pagination) can be done on the response of the propfind with depth infinity? as propfind with depth infinity returns big response...